# How do I use a while loop when dealing with an input that could raise an exception?

Tags: python, exception, while-loop

I'm working on code for my uni project and this one part requires the user to input a file name, and while the file name is not found, it should display a message and then prompt the user to display a valid filename. This is what I have so far but it stops after a second invalid input and I'm not sure how to use a while loop with this. If someone could help, that would be great. Thank you!

```
if user_choice == commands[2]: 
    try:
        file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
        print(INPUT(file_name))

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file name you entered does not exist.")
        file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
```

Comment: *If you build in something that will break the loop once a valid file is given*, you can do `while True:`; but if you don't put in a `break` statement, you'll create an infinite loop. You could also create a variable—set to `True` or `False`, and check that with the `while` loop; then, once a valid file is given, change the value so the condition evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a while loop and break when the file is found. so it would be something like this:

```
if user_choice == commands[2]: 
    while True:
        try:
            file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
            print(INPUT(file_name))
            #if the file is found (if statement) (I don't know how you would do this as i haven't seen the full code):
                break

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("The file name you entered does not exist.")
            file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
```

Comment: Just move the `break` out to be the same level as the `print`. It will break out of the while which is all that's needed.

Comment: @tdelaney Don't we need to find the file first? otherwise, it will only check once right?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```html
if user_choice == commands[2]: 

var = 0
while var != 1 :
  try:
        file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
        print(INPUT(file_name))
        var = 1

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file name you entered does not exist.")
        file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
```